# How to keep Safari Web Inspector open when debugging iOS Cordova application's crash?

Tags: ios, cordova, safari

I'm trying to investigate javascript-related memory leak issue in a Cordova application. Application is deployed to a device (iPhone, iOS 12) connected via USB and it can be inspected with Safari (12.0) on macOS (10.14).

In Safari, I can start recording of events from "Timelines" tab. When memory leak is severe enough for the application to crash, Safari Web Inspector is immediately shut down and the recorded timeline is lost.

How can I keep inspector open despite the crash?
If not possible, are recorded intermediate timeline logs saved to somewhere so I could analyze them post-crash?